# SQL Query Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I stuck in a SQL query,

I have a table salary whose structure is as follow :

```
Name Amount
a     100
b     300
c     250
```

I have to write a query which gives the following result :

```
 Name Amount RelevantAmount
    a     100    100
    b     300    400
    c     250    650
```

I didn't found any idea that how to write this query without using any cursor and trigger.

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: How do you define RelevantAmount?

Comment: Exactly how do you derive those "RelevantAmount" values? Are they pulled out of a magic hat?

Comment: where does `RelevantAmount` come from?

Comment: I am using SQL sever 2008 an dby viewing its clear the logic of question.

Comment: RelevantAmount looks like the cumulative sum of Amount. This value would be dependent on the order of the rows.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are looking to sum up the amounts of everything higher up on the list and including the current line, a simplest to understand (but not necessarily the most efficient) answer would use a correlated query:

```
select
    name
,   amount
,   (select sum(amount) from MyTable t2 where t1.name <= t2.name) RelevantAmount
from MyTable t1
order by t1.Name
```

Comment: What SQL implementations support "less than or equal" operator for strings?

Comment: @Li0liQ I am reasonably certain that many RDBMS servers do. I just verified that my SQL Server 2008 R2 does.

Comment: @Li0liQ: All SQL DBMS that claim to be standard compliant support all 6 comparative operators for strings, and most DBMS that don't claim to be standard compliant do so too.  I've never heard of one that didn't, though I suppose it is conceivable.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Name, a.Amount, SUM(b.Amount) as RelevantAmount
FROM myTable a
    JOIN myTable b
        ON b.Name <= a.Name
GROUP BY a.Name, a.Amount
ORDER BY a.Name ASC
```

Comment: i tried this but this didnot give me the desired result

Comment: It would if the ON condition was `b.Name <= a.Name`.

Comment: yep - my bad.  read your question too fast and thought the amounts were also in ascending order.  I'll edit the query to join on b.Name <= a.Name

Answer (score 2):

As per i understand your question, you could do:

```
SELECT name,
SUM(amount) AS month_amount,
SUM(SUM(amount)) OVER
(ORDER BY amount ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
AS cumulative_amount
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name;
```